# Create type for parent HOC props depending on existing child properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, expo

I'm making a high order component (HOC) for `@expo/vector-icons` and trying to define the general type for its props. There are several icon source `components` inside the module (`MaterialCommunityIcons`, `MaterialIcons`, `FontAwesome` etc.) and all of them have got the same shape but unique literal types for icon `names`.

So, HOC should receive two props: source `component` and icon's `name`. And the idea is, when the `component` is defined, the `name` prop should infer an appropriate list of available names for the selected source. My attempt looks like this:

```js
const IconLibs = { MaterialCommunityIcons, MaterialIcons, FontAwesome };

type IconLibsNames = keyof typeof IconLibs;

type HocProps<Key extends IconLibsNames> = {
    component: typeof IconLibs[Key];
    name: React.ComponentProps<typeof IconLibs[Key]>["name"];
};
```

In my result I see, that all `names` are gathering in general list and all of them are available for each source `component`. How to split them correctly?

If it would be helpful, literal type of appropriate `component`'s `names` (for example, `"stop" | "forward" | "check" | "close" | "book" ...`) could be taken in two ways:

1.

```js
type name = React.ComponentProps<typeof MaterialIcons>["name"]
```

2. 

```js
type name = keyof typeof MaterialIcons.glyphMap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the promlem is that you tried to infer name using generic + `typeof`. I would recommend using more straightforward approach:

```
const IconLibs = { MaterialCommunityIcons, MaterialIcons, FontAwesome };

type IconComponent = typeof IconLibs[keyof typeof IconLibs]

type HocProps<TComponent extends IconComponent> = {
    component: TComponent;
    name: React.ComponentProps<TComponent>['name']
};


const hoc = <TComponent extends IconComponent>({name, component}: HocProps<TComponent>) => {
  // implementation of hoc
}

hoc({component: FontAwesome, name: '...'}) // `name` will be inferred from the FontAwesome
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks Flat Globe. What's left for me to do is figure out how)))